# Run jmap command failed in MacOS

Tags: java, macos, jvm

Run `jmap` as follows:

```
jmap -heap 5788
```

And get failed result:

Attaching to process ID 5788, please wait...
Error attaching to process:

```
sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.DebuggerException: Can't attach symbolicator to the process
sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.DebuggerException: sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.DebuggerException: Can't attach symbolicator to the process
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.bsd.BsdDebuggerLocal$BsdDebuggerLocalWorkerThread.execute(BsdDebuggerLocal.java:169)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.bsd.BsdDebuggerLocal.attach(BsdDebuggerLocal.java:287)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.HotSpotAgent.attachDebugger(HotSpotAgent.java:671)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.HotSpotAgent.setupDebuggerDarwin(HotSpotAgent.java:659)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.HotSpotAgent.setupDebugger(HotSpotAgent.java:341)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.HotSpotAgent.go(HotSpotAgent.java:304)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.HotSpotAgent.attach(HotSpotAgent.java:140)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.Tool.start(Tool.java:185)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.Tool.execute(Tool.java:118)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.JInfo.main(JInfo.java:138)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.tools.jinfo.JInfo.runTool(JInfo.java:108)
    at sun.tools.jinfo.JInfo.main(JInfo.java:76)
Caused by: sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.DebuggerException: Can't attach symbolicator to the process
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.bsd.BsdDebuggerLocal.attach0(Native Method)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.bsd.BsdDebuggerLocal.access$100(BsdDebuggerLocal.java:65)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.bsd.BsdDebuggerLocal$1AttachTask.doit(BsdDebuggerLocal.java:278)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.bsd.BsdDebuggerLocal$BsdDebuggerLocalWorkerThread.run(BsdDebuggerLocal.java:144)
```

Comment: Which version of java you are using here ?

Comment: @DarkKnight  1.8

Comment: I guess this issue is fixed for version 9, not sure about 8. Try upgrading minor version of jdk at your end, if this does not work you have no option but to move to 9. Please refer https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8160376

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the symbolicator attempts to symbolicate the macOS kernel, which fails due to permissions on macOS.

On newer versions, you can use jshdb:

```
 jhsdb jmap --heap --pid <pid>
```

You can also get information using `jcmd <pid> GC.heap_info`.

Answer (score 0):

you need to codesign `sa-jdi.jar`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.cs.debugger</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

```
codesign --entitlements entitlement.xml -fs debug_cert /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_321.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/sa-jdi.jar
```